# jquery .each() loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, each

i want to read all links in ".vm-video-title"-divs and post them each in the same div. So i made this script:

```
$('.vm-video-title').each(function(i) {//all divs
    $(this).html($(this).html()+$("div.vm-video-title>a").text());//add to div the link
    });
```

but i have the problem that it reads ALL the links of all divs and put them in one div.

example:

```
<div class="vm-video-title"><a href="...">Text1</a></div>
<div class="vm-video-title"><a href="...">Text2</a></div>
<div class="vm-video-title"><a href="...">Text3</a></div>
```

output:

```
<a href="...">Text1</a>Text1Text2Text3
<a href="...">Text2</a>Text1Text2Text3
<a href="...">Text3</a>Text1Text2Text3
```

wanted output:

```
<a href="...">Text1</a>Text1
<a href="...">Text2</a>Text2
<a href="...">Text3</a>Text3
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do the job for you,

you need to find the div inside current element in the loop (el).

```
$('.vm-video-title').each(function(i, el) {
    el = $(el);
    el.html(el.html()+el.find("a").text());
});
```

in your code you are adding text() of all matching "a" tags in your divs (i.e. Text1Text2Text3)

Answer (score 5):

You can select the `<a>` elements directly, and use the [`after()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/after/) method to append the content of each after each one respectively.

```
$("div.vm-video-title > a").after(function() { return $(this).text(); });
```

This doesn't do a *"destroy then recreate"* of the existing elements like the [`html()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/html/) method  will.

**Working example:** http://jsfiddle.net/CCr9C/

Answer (score 2):

You were almost there. Instead of : `$("div.vm-video-title").text()`, which gives you text inside any `div` with class `vm-video-title`, you need to find `a` tag inside current `div` and get text from it. We pass `this` as `context` for selecting `a` inside current `div` **`jQuery( selector, [context] )`**

```
$('.vm-video-title').each(function(i) {//all divs
   $(this).html($(this).html()+$("a", this).text());
});
```

Comment: using "this" is always confusing in js, using a named variable is recommended wherever possible. function(i, el) in this case.

Comment: @patrick's method (`after`) is better as it will not recreate dom elements.